# Windows 10 Creating and deleting directory in remote location (Netapp) in a loop fails after some iterations

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

Some of our tests programs create directory, writes some files there and deletes it.  These tests started failing recently after we moved to  Windows10 (from Windows7)

The tests were in Java -   Later the test case reduced to small sequence 
* Create directory, Delete directory.
* A File creation and write to file was added to get the errors more easily

After some error (powershell newbie) the error was re-created with powershell.

I believe this could be environment issue or some new issue with Windows10 (Version 1909)

The remote location is a NetApp filer location exposing CIFS for Windows. Script is below.
The error did not happen with Local disk  of the VM or another remote location which is plain Windows Share

```
#preparation  
$strRoot = $env:REMOTE_UNC_PATH 


New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $strRoot -Force -ErrorAction Continue

$sleepMillis = $env:SLEEP_TIME_MILLIS
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$strTestdir = "$strRoot\testdir"
$strPathFile =  "$strTestdir\sample.txt"


#actual test cases
For ($i=0; $i -lt 1000 ; $i++) {
    Write-Output "Iteration $i " 

    Write-Output "Iteration $i Create directory : $strTestdir " 
    New-Item  -ItemType "directory" -Path $strTestdir -ErrorAction Stop

    Write-Output "Iteration $i  Write a file $strPathFile  " 
    New-Item  -ItemType "file"     -Path $strPathFile -ErrorAction Stop

    Write-Output "Iteration $i  remove the file  $strPathFile  " 
    Remove-Item -Force  $strPathFile  -ErrorAction Stop

    Write-Output "Iteration $i  remove the directory $strTestdir" 
    Remove-Item -Force  -Recurse $strTestdir  -ErrorAction Stop

    Write-Output "Iteration $i Sleep for   $sleepMillis  milliseconds"
    Start-Sleep      -Milliseconds  $sleepMillis 
}

exit  $LastExitCode
```

The error could happen at any line

- Directory created but you cannot create file
- File created but cannot    be deleted etc

Logs from last run

```
    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----       23/12/2019     09:14                testdir                                                               
Iteration 4  Write a file //ies-net-cls1-data.ies.mentorg.com/iesd_data3_nb/jayandir\testdir\sample.txt  


    Directory: \\ies-net-cls1-data.ies.mentorg.com\iesd_data3_nb\jayandir\testdir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
-a----       23/12/2019     09:14              0 sample.txt                                                            
Iteration 4  remove the file  //ies-net-cls1-data.ies.mentorg.com/iesd_data3_nb/jayandir\testdir\sample.txt  
Iteration 4  remove the directory //ies-net-cls1-data.ies.mentorg.com/iesd_data3_nb/jayandir\testdir
Iteration 4 Sleep for   3  milliseconds
Iteration 5 
Iteration 5 Create directory : //ies-net-cls1-data.ies.mentorg.com/iesd_data3_nb/jayandir\testdir 
New-Item : An item with the specified name \\ies-net-cls1-data.ies.mentorg.com\iesd_data3_nb\jayandir\testdir already 
exists.
At C:\Users\iesdgrid\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins8492477017526245143.ps1:19 char:6
+         New-Item  -ItemType "directory" -Path $strTestdir -ErrorActio ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (\\ies-net-cls1-...ayandir\testdir:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
New run name is '#26 - sleep 3'
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

Machine : VM with 2 vCPU, 8G RAM, Operating System: Windows 10 1909 build
Remote location: NetApp CIFS location

Note after searches : This looks like somewhat related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439670/files-move-file-renameto-both-fail-after-many-iterations-windows-10-definit (Files.move / file.renameTo both fail after many iterations (Windows 10),)  -- but reproduced with powershell

Comment: The error always is accompanied with some error message. Where is it?

Comment: Can you get a Process Monitor trace of this? I would include the System process.

Comment: Check for error messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: @ HelpingHand  : What information from ProcessMonitor will be relevant? It is very huge

Comment: @harrymc: thanks, what events should I filter for?  Too many events at the moment.

Comment: I suggest to start by filtering for errors - [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2014/08/06/quick-tip-event-viewer-filtering/).

Comment: Waiting after applying recommendations from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN (all three -- DirectoryCacheLifetime, FileNotFoundCacheLifetime, FileInfoCacheLifetime  set to 0 )

Comment: that did not help